# neo4j CREATE UNIQUE seems very slow

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to create a bunch of relationships where Foo is 'IN' Bar for a series of time ranges.

My basic query looks something like this:

```
MERGE (f:Foo {id: 123})
MERGE (b111:Bar {id: 111})
CREATE UNIQUE (f) - [:IN { from:130958270580000000, to: 130958975440000000 } ] -> (b111)
```

This functionally does exactly what I'm after but as I add may create statements the query gets very slow. Looping this statement is also very slow.

eg:

```
MERGE (f:Foo {id: 123})
MERGE (b111:Bar {id: 111})
MERGE (b222:Bar {id: 222})
CREATE UNIQUE (f) - [:IN { from:130958270580000000, to: 130958975440000000 } ] -> (b111)
CREATE UNIQUE (f) - [:IN { from:130954640800000000, to: 130954728070000000 } ] -> (b111)
CREATE UNIQUE (f) - [:IN { from:130954563680000000, to: 130954563920000000 } ] -> (b111)
CREATE UNIQUE (f) - [:IN { from:130954559880000000, to: 130954559900000000 } ] -> (b111)
CREATE UNIQUE (f) - [:IN { from:130954557300000000, to: 130954559300000000 } ] -> (b111)
CREATE UNIQUE (f) - [:IN { from:130954556860000000, to: 130954557100000000 } ] -> (b111)
CREATE UNIQUE (f) - [:IN { from:130953825060000000, to: 130954554060000000 } ] -> (b111)
CREATE UNIQUE (f) - [:IN { from:130953080610000000, to: 130953807160000000 } ] -> (b111)
CREATE UNIQUE (f) - [:IN { from:130948659890000000, to: 130952852200000000 } ] -> (b111)
CREATE UNIQUE (f) - [:IN { from:130947989650000000, to: 130948493470000000 } ] -> (b111)
CREATE UNIQUE (f) - [:IN { from:130947129060000000, to: 130947675200000000 } ] -> (b222)
```

For example if I create 400 relationships like this it takes 23s

I ran PROFILE for the above and it looks like it is doing a lot of db hits for this statement (586 total db hits in 158 ms.) which seems weird. This seems to increase exponentially as I add more CREATE statements.

I have tried adding indices to Foo and Bar as well but they didn't seem to make any difference.

I'm super new to neo4j so I'm probably doing something stupid or making a false assumption somewhere but I cant work out why this query should be so slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slowdown isn't with matching on your nodes, it's from CREATE UNIQUE on your relationships (MERGE would also suffer the same slowness). What it comes down to is that non-indexed property access can be expensive in neo4j.

There are no indexes on relationships, so any CREATE UNIQUE or MERGE operation like what you have above must scan all relationships of that type and compare property values to see if that relationship already exists. Obviously the cost will grow with the number of relationships of that type that are present.

There are a couple ways to mitigate this.

If you know for a fact that these relationships with those specific properties don't exist yet, just use CREATE instead of CREATE UNIQUE. You can run a query to check at the end of your relationship creation if you goofed anywhere and have a duplicate you can remove.

An alternate is to adjust your model. Rather than having properties present on the relationship itself, create an intermediate node with its own label between :Foo and :Bar nodes, and use that to hold your from and to properties. You'll want to index those properties to avoid the MERGE or CREATE UNIQUE slowdown.

I recommend having an intermediate node, especially if you plan to use queries that involve those time properties, and if there are bound to be many of them. If those properties are only on relationships, you cannot take advantage of indexes to speed up your queries, which may be a problem for you later.

EDIT

Usage of an intermediate node might look like this (assume indexes on :Foobar(from) and :Foobar(to)):

```
MERGE (f:Foo {id: 123})
MERGE (f2:Foo {id: 456})
MERGE (b111:Bar {id: 111})
MERGE (b222:Bar {id: 222})
MERGE (f) - [:IN] -> (fb:Foobar{ from:130958270580000000, to: 130958975440000000 })
MERGE (fb) - [:IN] -> (b111)
WITH f, f2, b111, b222
// merge with same :Foobar values on f2...should create a new node
// instead of reusing the one attached to f.
MERGE (f2) - [:IN] -> (fb:Foobar{ from:130958270580000000, to: 130958975440000000 })
MERGE (fb) - [:IN] -> (b111)
WITH f, f2, b111, b222
MERGE (f) - [:IN] -> (fb:Foobar{ from:130954640800000000, to: 130954728070000000 })
MERGE (fb) - [:IN] -> (b111)
WITH f, f2, b111, b222
MERGE (f) - [:IN] -> (fb:Foobar{ from:130954563680000000, to: 130954563920000000 })
MERGE (fb) - [:IN] -> (b111)
...
```

Of course you may have to rename your relationships and labels to something more sensible, if possible.

A query using this might look like this:

```
// find which :Bar f was in at a particular instance
WITH {params.instance} as instance
MATCH (f:Foo {id: 123})-[:IN]->(fb:Foobar)
WHERE fb.from <= instance <= fb.to
WITH fb
MATCH (fb)-[:IN]->(b:Bar)
RETURN b
```

EDIT Altered the insert query to enforce uniqueness of the :Foobar node to the corresponding :Foo node, which will prevent a MERGE from matching on an existing :Foobar node already in use by another :Foo.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense. I tried changing this to a CREATE (without unique) but it made basically no difference to the times. In terms of splitting it to a separate node, I don't think I could easily do this, the actual uniqueness is the relationship (eg foo:1 is in bar:2 between these times). I cant think of any way to sensibly split this into a new node? I assume it would be silly to also include some identifier to the foo and bar on the new entity to give the uniqueness?

Comment: Actually for some reason its still slow but the number of db hits has dropped drastically with CREATE (not unique)

Comment: Unsure about the slowness, but I added some examples of both using and querying using an intermediate node. Keep in mind that while db creation times are a concern, the greater concern is your query performance, so use that as a better benchmark of what kind of modeling to use. PROFILE is your friend.

Comment: If the times are the same for two different relationships wont that create some weirdness, Eg if foo:1 is in bar:1 from 1-2 and foo:2 is in bar:2 from 1-2 wont that mean foo:1 is in both bar:1 and bar:2 from 1-2? Eg there will be one foobar when there should be two?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. By foo:1 and foo:2, you're referring to two separate :Foo nodes? If so, then the relationships (and corresponding :Foobar nodes) of one :Foo node should be independent of those of any other :Foobar node. One :Foobar node should only have relationships to one :Foo node and one :Bar node. If you're talking about multiple times overlapping for the :Foobar nodes for a single :Foo node, then that's a data input problem that you have to solve. Neither the original data model nor mine will solve that for you.

Comment: Yeah 2 separate foos and 2 separate bars. the problem is that if there is a unique foobar (`MERGE (fb:Foobar { from:1, to: 2 })`) then it will have a total of 4 relationships, foo:1, foo:2, bar:1, bar:2 which means each foo will be related to both bars when we only intended it to be related to one. The only way I can think of to get around that would be to include an ID for foo and bar on foobar and `MERGE (fb:Foobar { from:1, to: 2, foo:1, bar:1 })` but that seems a bit weird in a graph DB like I'm trying to have foreign keys

Comment: Ah, I see, my mistake. We do need uniqueness, but with respect to the corresponding :Foo node, not against all :Foobar nodes. I altered my insert query to not MERGE on the :Foobar node alone, but on the pattern connecting it to the :Foo node we want to attach it to. I also added an f2 :Foo node, and added a MERGE to a :Foobar node with the same to and from as the one used for f, and it creates a separate :Foobar node, as it should, rather than matching to the existing one. Give that a try.

Comment: That's super cool how that match works on a relationship. I had no idea you could do that. I think doing all this definitely makes things faster but its still very slow over all. I think maybe I need to re-frame my problem a bit. I think I will mark this as answer as this definitely solves the specific issue around Create Unique (which I think was about tripling my query times). I think i have another issue with volume of relationships, but I will have a bit more of a think and ask that separately. Thanks heaps for your help and bearing with me, much appreciated :)